# sklearn ColumnTransformer does not work with pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn

I have the following code. What I want to do is to apply different transformers to every column of a pandas dataframe. For the beginning, I want just my two columns passthrough without any transforms.

```py
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.compose import ColumnTransformer

df = pd.DataFrame({'pre0': [2, 0, 1, 2], 'pre1': [99, 56, 85, 78]})
column_meta_data = [("p1", "passthrough", "pre0"), ("p2", "passthrough", "pre1")]
column_transformer = ColumnTransformer(transformers=column_meta_data)
X_ = column_transformer.fit_transform(df)
```

I get the following error:

```py
ValueError: The output of the 'p1' transformer should be 2D (scipy matrix, array, or pandas DataFrame).
```

This is weird since the columns of the pandas dataframe should already be one dimensional. What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think maybe in the definition of columns, as in [here](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.compose.ColumnTransformer.html):

"**columnsstr, array-like of str, int, array-like of int, array-like of bool, slice or callable.** Indexes the data on its second axis. Integers are interpreted as positional columns, while strings can reference DataFrame columns by name. A scalar string or int should be used where transformer expects X to be a 1d array-like (vector), otherwise a 2d array will be passed to the transformer. A callable is passed the input data X and can return any of the above. To select multiple columns by name or dtype, you can use make_column_selector."

**In practical terms**. Instead of

```
column_meta_data = [("p1", "passthrough", "pre0"), ("p2", "passthrough", "pre1")]
```

this one:

```
column_meta_data = [("p1", "passthrough", ["pre0"]), ("p2", "passthrough", ["pre1"])]
```

or

```
column_meta_data = [("p1", "passthrough", ["pre0","pre1"])]
```